# Is it a good practice to log error inside exception constructor?

Tags: c#, exception, logging

I'm developing a web application in C#, and I have a special exception type, that I need to have a full log from its happenings, and of course I'm going to handle that to show a special message to the user or something.

The question is, is it a good practice to write logging codes inside exception's constructor? I'm asking this because I have not seen something similar to this before.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No; constructors should not have side-effects.

Comment: I'd assume not since the logging itself is capable of throwing an exception it can get very convoluted

Comment: The exception is the last line of defense to handle problems. Once you open it up to code that has the possibility of breaking, that kind of defeats the purpose of the exception. Best to keep them separated.

Comment: IMHO, this breaks single responsibility principle. Don't do that. Exceptions are should be responsible only throwing.

Comment: What do you think about this way: Rethrowing exception after local handlings, and catching and logging that in a global exception filter?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what's wrong with simply catching the exception and logging in the catch block? That seems pretty standard. This really looks like you're trying to reinvent a wheel that's already round.

Comment: @DrewKennedy My problem is with copying log codes in every catch block

Comment: Gotcha. I can see how it would be appealing as it could be more efficient in the writing of code, but it's a bad design.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A short and good answer should be: **no, you shouldn't go this way becuase you want to develop your code with a good separation of concerns: exception handling isn't logging, thus, logging can't be part of constructing an exception**.

If that exception is not handled by your code, you can use a last-chance exception handler like `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event and log it there.